# ¿Cómo graficar en una interfaz gráfica usando MatplotLib los valores recibidos de un sensor?

Tags: python, archivo, matplotlib, interfaz-gráfica, arduino

Estoy desarrollando una interfaz gráfica que te pida el nombre del archivo nuevo que se va a generar de tipo txt y que te pregunte el puerto serial en el que se encuentra tu Arduino, al iniciar el programa python se conecta a Arduino con el puerto específico y recibe 25 datos del sensor(use un potenciometro para realizar las pruebas) y estos datos recibidos se escriben en el archivo de texto, además de esto para mostrar en la interfaz gráfica los resultados los pondría en una gráfica. Los problemas que he encontrado para cumplir mi objetivo son los siguientes

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

(**Solucionado**) Lee los datos como bytes así que cuando los guarda en el archivo de texto los almacena de este modo

```
b'NUMERO\r\n'
```

y esto ocasiona que cuando quiera usar replace('b\r\n','') me de un

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

---

**al usar `lectura_str=lectura.decode("utf8")`al guardar ese valor en la variable `texto` ya no eran bytes**

---

(**Al parecer son son dos sucesos correlacionados)**
Esto a su vez ocasiona que cuando grafica los datos no se pongan en orden ascendente sino por aparición(**me imagino que es porque tengo que definir cómo se debería de comportar Y <de manera ascendente de 0 a 1024> y es por eso que se ponen así**)

[image: Valores recibidos del sensor graficados]

De momento no se como plasmar esta gráfica que se genera en la interfaz cuando termina pero si no soluciono esto primero no servirá de nada.(**solucionado**)

Dejo la parte donde intento remplazar comentada para que sepan en que parte la puse, aquí mi código de python

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from tkinter import*
import serial, time
def crearTEXTO(lectura):
    texto=''
    for i in range(len(lectura)):
        lectura_str=lectura[i].decode("utf8")
        texto += str(lectura_str)
    return texto

def graficar(lectura):
    y=[]
    for i in range(len(lectura)):
        y.append(lectura[i])
    return y

def ENVIAR():
    NAME=str(NOMBRE.get())
    PORT=str(PUERTO.get())
    PORT=str(PUERTO.get())
    try:
        arduino = serial.Serial(PORT,9600)
        time.sleep(4)#Estabilizar la conección
        for i in range(25):
            arduino.write(b'1')#Aquí se envían bits
        lectura=[]
        
        for i in range(25):
            lectura.append(arduino.readline())
        arduino.close()
        
        # for i in range(len(lectura)):
        #     lectura[i][len(lectura[i])-1] = lectura[i][len(lectura[i])-1].replace('b\r\n','')
    except:
        messagebox.showinfo(message="Por favor verifica que el Puerto que pusiste sea el correcto", title="ERROR")

    archivo = open(NAME+".txt","w") #Abrimos el archivo en modalidad escritura "write"
    text=crearTEXTO(lectura)

    archivo.write(text)
    archivo.close()
    print(text)
    y=graficar(lectura)
    plt.plot(y)

    # plt.show

POTENCIOMETRO = Tk()
marco = Frame(POTENCIOMETRO)

#Objetos a utilizar
ASKNAME = Label(marco,text= "Bienvenido, ¿Qué nombre tendrá este archivo nuevo?")
NOMBRE = Entry(marco)
ASKPORT = Label(marco,text= "¿En qué puerto está conectado tu ARDUINO UNO?")
PUERTO = Entry(marco)
ENVIAR= Button(marco, text = "ENVIAR", command = ENVIAR)


#Contenido
ASKNAME.pack()
NOMBRE.pack()
ASKPORT.pack()
PUERTO.pack()
ENVIAR.pack()
marco.pack(padx = 200, pady=150)#Tamaño márco
POTENCIOMETRO.mainloop()
```

Y aquí está mi código de Arduino, el que estoy usando es Arduino Uno y así está conectado todo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
int s = 0;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(A2, INPUT);

}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.read() == '1') {
    delay(1000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
      s = analogRead(A2);
      delay(500);
      Serial.println(s);

    }
  }
}
```

como habrán visto puse  un `print(text)` para visualizar desde la consola de python sin abrir el archivo.txt lo que se guardaba, aquí les dejo que es lo que se imprimía

```
b'1016\r\n' b'1019\r\n' b'1016\r\n' b'1018\r\n' b'1016\r\n' b'1017\r\n' b'1019\r\n' b'1018\r\n' b'1016\r\n' b'1018\r\n' b'1018\r\n' b'965\r\n' b'1016\r\n' b'1002\r\n' b'1018\r\n' b'781\r\n' b'1019\r\n' b'1018\r\n' b'1019\r\n' b'1019\r\n' b'1019\r\n' b'1019\r\n' b'811\r\n' b'418\r\n' b'369\r\n'
```

(**y lo que se imprime ahora**)

```
195
217
242
275
359
424
459
383
428
575
763
1018
884
559
488
418
350
333
283
340
413
462
685
839
518
```

el programa esta hecho para que de igual forma la gráfica se muestre en la consola de python hasta que se cierra el programa (**pero desearía que aparezca la gráfica en la misma interfaz**)

Comment: Que es lo que quieres gráficar específicamente?

Comment: Lo que detecta el potenciometro @gcoronel99

Comment: Ok, pero cuál es la x y cuál es la y? (Datos verticales, horizontales). Me refiero a que datos quieres medir y por qué medida.

Comment: lista[i](f(x))=i(x)
i iría de 0 a 24 y lista[i] son los datos que recibe el sensor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que recibes desde Arduino son *bytes*.

A diferencia de C, en Python las secuencias de bytes y strings son dos tipos diferentes de datos. Para transformar el primero en el segundo, usa `decode`:

```
valor = b'NUMERO\r\n'
valor_str = valor.decode("utf8")
print(valor, type(valor))
print(valor_str, type(valor_str))
valor_str = valor_str.strip()
print("Valor simplificado: >%s<" % valor_str)
```

Nota: el valor original no contiene una "b" al principio. Eso lo agrega Python al desplegarlo para señalar que el tipo de la variable es `bytes`, no `str`. Por tanto, sólo queda eliminar los espacios en blanco (whitespace) alrededor usando `strip()`, que es más general que simplemente `replace("\r\n","")`.

Produce:

```
b'NUMERO\r\n' <class 'bytes'>
NUMERO
 <class 'str'>
Valor simplificado: >NUMERO<
```

Nota: Existe microPython para ESP8266 y ESP32. He estado trabajando con ESP32 + microPython ultimamente y es una maravilla, 100 veces más poderoso y fácil. Te recomiendo el upgrade.

Comment: Y con respecto a graficar, que debería hacer para mostrar la grafica en la interfaz?

Comment: @Santiago No tengo experiencia con tkinter. Podrías experimentar con un programa separado, que tenga los datos en una lista. Si no te resulta la gráfica, puedes hacer otro pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Sobre la integración con Arduino, te recomiendo que le des un vistazo a la libreria pyFirmata. Instalar Firmata en Arduino y no tienes que hacer nada más por ese lado. El control de este módulo se hará desde Python y tendrás todo el código uniforme en un solo script.

Por otro lado, para esta aplicación lo conveniente es utilizar un `deque` (cola), que es una especie de lista especial que tiene un tamaño fijo y que cuando se alimenta un valor con `append` este se inserta al final de la cola y hace que el primer valor salga de la cola. De esta manera siempre tienes una estructura con la misma cantidad de valores y hará que tu gráfico en matplotlib muestre la variación. Esto esta disponible en `from collections import deque`.

Luego, si quieres insertar un gráfico de matplotlib en tkinter lo pueds hacer con un widget especial de figura, `FigureCanvasTkAgg`.

Te dejo un programa que hace algo parecido a lo que estas haciendo, solo que lee valores del estado de la PC con la librería `psutil` (lee el uso del CPU). Adaptarlo a los valores leídos por el puerto serial es sencillo. Estos valores se utilizan para actualizar la cola de valores y se actualiza constantemente la gráfica (cada segundo) por medio del método `after` sobre la ventana principal y eliminando el axes gráfico (`ax.cla()`).

```
import psutil
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from collections import deque

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("CPU Data Dashboard")
        self.master.resizable(0, 0)
        self.master.config(background='black')

        self.var_usage_CPU = tk.DoubleVar()
        self.var_usage_MEM = tk.DoubleVar()
        self.var_battery_percent = tk.IntVar(value=50)

        self.plot_line = deque(maxlen=10)

        frm = tk.Frame(background='black')
        frm.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        
        self.lblCPU_Usage = tk.Label(frm, text="", bg='black', fg='white')
        self.barCPU_Usage = ttk.Progressbar(frm, length=200, variable=self.var_usage_CPU)
        self.lblMEM_Usage = tk.Label(frm, text="", bg='black', fg='white')
        self.barMEM_Usage = ttk.Progressbar(frm, length=200, variable=self.var_usage_MEM, 
                                            maximum=psutil.virtual_memory().total)
        self.lblBAT_Usage = tk.Label(frm, text="", bg='black', fg='white')
        self.barBAT_Usage = ttk.Progressbar(frm, length=200, variable=self.var_battery_percent)

        self.lblCPU_Usage.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W)
        self.barCPU_Usage.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W)
        self.lblMEM_Usage.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W)
        self.barMEM_Usage.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W)
        self.lblBAT_Usage.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W)
        self.barBAT_Usage.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W)

        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3, 2))
        self.fig.set_facecolor('black')
        
        self.graph = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=frm)
        self.graph.get_tk_widget().grid(row=6, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.ax.set_title("CPU Usage Percent")
        self.ax.set_ylabel("%")
        self.ax.set_yticklabels(self.ax.get_yticks(), fontsize=8)
        self.ax.set_xticks([])
        self.ax.set_xlim(0, 100)

        self.read_psutil_data()


    def read_psutil_data(self):
        self.var_usage_CPU.set(psutil.cpu_percent())
        self.var_usage_MEM.set(psutil.virtual_memory().used)
        self.var_battery_percent.set(psutil.sensors_battery().percent)
        self.update_dashboard_data()


    def update_dashboard_data(self):
        self.lblCPU_Usage.config(text=f"CPU Usage: {self.var_usage_CPU.get()}%")
        self.lblMEM_Usage.config(text=f"Virtual Memory Usage: {self.var_usage_MEM.get()/1e6:,.1f} Mb")
        self.lblBAT_Usage.config(text=f"Battery Available: {self.var_battery_percent.get()}%")
       
        self.ax.cla()
        
        self.plot_line.append(self.var_usage_CPU.get())
        self.ax.plot(self.plot_line)
        self.ax.set_title("CPU Usage Percent", color='white')
        self.ax.set_yticklabels([0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100], color='white')
        self.ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
        self.ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
        self.ax.set_xticks([])
        self.ax.grid(linestyle='--')
        self.ax.set_facecolor('black')
        
        self.graph.draw()
        
        
        self.master.after(1000, self.read_psutil_data)


root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```